# Трансформация (парсинг) формата из xml в json + сохранение структуры документа

Tags: c#, json, xml

Проблема: Сохраняет в одну строку, нет отступов(пробелов, табуляций, переносов на новую).
Задание:Необходимо разработать приложение для трансформации структуры данных из XML в JSON.
Решение:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(inpxml);
string outjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
FileStream file = new FileStream(name, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
sw.WriteLine(outjson2);
```

Много перерыл информации и смотрел примеров и пробовал и читал в оригинале и про Newtonsoft, но не до конца разобрался. Знаю что есть вариант с написанием класса под конкретную структуру, что крайне сомнительный вариант. Хочется что бы получилось примерно так https://www.newtonsoft.com/JSON/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm.
Находил на форумах(за 13 год) еще информацию про создание динамического класса, но может есть какое то более простое решение или просто лучше ?

Comment: `string outjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);`

Comment: Век тебе без блокировок добрый человек !!! Забавно что с двумя параметрами я пробовал сериализацию, но тогда были другие проблемы в проге и я переключился на 1 параметр.

Comment: К тегам у которых несколько параметров или параметры с "" добавляется символ @ , это можно как то убрать ?

Comment: `@` - это атрибут. Вы хотели сохранить структуру xml, вы её сохранили. Но если очень уж хочется удалить, см. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43485727/5045688

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А в ответ вписать?

Answer (score 0):

```
string outjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Второй параметр как раз отвечает за форматирование, ранее я использовал метод без него, в этом ошибка.
Спасибо еще раз @AlexanderPetrov за ответ.